# BackgroundColor expression

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created a Base_Rent_Variance Calculated field that works like it should:

```
=IIF(Fields!CurrNrmRent.Value = 0 and Fields!PriorNrmRent.Value > 0, "Review", IIF(Fields!PriorNrmRent.Value = 0 and Fields!CurrNrmRent.Value > 0, "Review", IIF(Fields!CurrNrmRent.Value > 0 and Fields!PriorNrmRent.Value > 0, (Fields!CurrNrmRent.Value-Fields!PriorNrmRent.Value)/IIF(Fields!PriorNrmRent.Value = 0, 1, Fields!PriorNrmRent.Value), nothing)))
```

I am trying to create a BackgroundColor expression so that if Base_Rent_Variance >= 15% or <= -15%, the background color is red, and if it equals Review the color is red.  The expression I created is filling the background red correctly for the 15% variances but not the Review.  My expression is below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
=IIF(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value >= .15 or Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value <= -.15, "Red",iif(RTRIM(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) = "Review","Red","White"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with your datatypes. You're attempting to store both numeric and string types in the same field.  I would use a conversion to be sure you have the correct datatypes. This expression should handle the mismatched datatypes.

```
=IIF(CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) >= .15 or CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) <= -.15,
    "Red",
     IIF(TRIM(CStr(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value)) = "Review","Red","White"))
```

Another option to try is using the `InStr` function like the following.

```
=IIF(CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) >= .15 or CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) <= -.15,
    "Red",
     IIF(InStr(CStr(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value), "Review"),"Red","White"))
```

Based on the comment below, let's try this one with a switch statement. The following switch statement will evaluate the first expression, set the cell red if true, check the second expression, set the cell red if true, and finally set anything left to white.

```
=SWITCH(CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) >= .15 or CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) <= -.15, "Red",
        InStr(CStr(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value), "Review"),"Red",
        true, "White")
```

Comment: Well, that didn't work either and I tried using it in a SWITCH statement.  Thank you for explaining my issue in detail.  I am a business end user, not a SQL programmer, trying to self teach.  I've come a long way but lingo still throws me for a loop!

Comment: @SSRSNewbie Hmmm, seems like it should.  I just added another option you can try that uses `InStr` to find "Review" in the field.  Eliminates the need for `TRIM` and should work if the field contains that search term.

Comment: I dumbed down the expression, and just tried =IIF(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value = "Review", "Red", "White").  This expression filled in all of the "Review" values in Red.  Additionally, I just tried =IIF(CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) >= .15 or CDbl(Fields!Base_Rent_Variance.Value) <= -.15,
    "Red", "White").  This also worked.  When using your expression above, it only returns the >= .15 or <= -.15 values as Red.  The expressions work separately, but not together.  Not sure what this tells me?

Comment: @SSRSNewbie Added another expression using `SWITCH`.  Maybe this latest expression will do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `me.Value` in colour expressions.

For example:

```
=iif(me.Value = "Review" OrElse me.Value >= 0.15 OrElse me.Value <= -0.15, "Red", "NoColor")
```

This means you don't have to recalculate your values each time, or keep track of changes in several locations if the calculations change.